# curve fitting of a part of the original plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I want to do curve fit for this plot of f only in the part where x is from 0.0001 to 0.007 and where y is from 0.00000001 to 0.0000009 . i hv tried so much through curve fit tool boxes using exclusion rule but didn't get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
x =0:32/1024000:32;

m = ( x &lt;= 16) .* ... % select the first part 
(  0.0133   0.00002./((cos(pi/4)./sinh(0.5*log(0.05*x))) coth(0.5*log(0.05*x))) )   ...
( x &gt; 16) .* ... % select second part
(  0.0133   0.00002./((cos(pi/4)./sinh(0.5*log(0.05*(32-x)))) coth(0.5*log(0.05*(32-x)))) ) ; 

k = ( x &lt;= 16) .* ... % select the first part
(  -0.00004*cos(pi/4)./(cosh(0.5*log(0.05*x))  sin(pi/4)) ) - ... 
( x &gt; 16) .* ... % select second part
(  -0.00004*cos(pi/4)./(cosh(0.5*log(0.05*(32-x)))  sin(pi/4)) ) ; 

z = complex(m,k); 
y = ifft(z); 
f = abs(y);
figure(1);
plot(x,(f));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to `excludedata` function with the `range` method name. I'm having trouble understanding your function so here's an example:

```
% x1 and y1 defined over the entire range
x1 = 1:1000;
y1 = 100*sin(x1/500) + 10*rand(size(x1));

% exclude y values less than 20 and greater than 60
e = excludedata(x1', y1', 'range', [20,60]);

% calculate a linear fit
f = fit(x1', y1', 'poly1', 'Exclude', e);

figure
hold on
plot(f,x1,y1)
```

[image: data with fit from a range of the data]